# Are LED stumps allowed by the Laws of Cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket, equipment

Cricket's [Law 8.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-8-the-wickets/) states

> Two sets of wickets shall be pitched opposite and parallel to each
>   other at a distance of 22 yards/20.12 m between the centres of the two
>   middle stumps. Each set shall be 9 in/22.86 cm wide and shall consist
>   of **three wooden stumps with two wooden bails on top**. See Appendix A.

Have there been any recent changes in this law, and if not why are LED stumps allowed in international matches? Are the LED stumps counted as "wooden", or am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is allowed by the playing conditions for the specific matches. For example, see the [2016 World T20 regulations](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/56bb2a65a7f53-Men's%20World%20T20%20Playing%20Conditions%20Clean%20Copy%20090216.pdf):

> 8.2 [...] The use of LED wickets is permitted.